# YouTube API V3 - Get 'Music' data if available

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to use the YouTube API to extract the 'Music' data, if available, from a video. For example:

```
Music  "Rolling In The Deep" by Adele ( • )
```

I have yet to find a way to do it after looking through the documentation.

Comment: Hi Adam, are you still experiencing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the [Terms of Service of the YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms?hl=fr) 
You cannot separate, isolate or modify the audio or video components of any YouTube audiovisual content made available through the YouTube API.

You cannot promote separately the audio or video components of any YouTube audiovisual content made available through the YouTube API.

For more information regarding Terms of Service, please check it here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms?hl=fr